# Powershell change viso container header color and other attibute

Tags: powershell

I was able to draw viso containers with powershell, now I want to format them but it doesn't look like any other shapes.
I tried the following command

```
$Master=$stencil.Masters('Classic')
$container = $Page.Drop($Master,4,4)
$container.cells("FillForegnd").formula = "RGB(1,1,1)"
```

but it respone the following error.

```
Cell is guarded.
At F:\work\powershell\auto draw viso\code1.ps1:37 char:1
+ $container.cells("FillForegnd").formula = "RGB(1,1,1)"
```

I know a container is a combie of shape, so I need to find the right object then change its color, but how can I find that object?

Thank you for your help

Comment: @Mike Shepard Looking forward to your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

for each rectangle itemID will increase by 1

The container will increase by 5 because there are 5 objects in it

and the fourth object of container object is the color fillable header.

so just by calculating the itemID then I can use the following formula to color the container

```
$page.shapes.ItemFromID($itemid).cells("FillForegnd").formula = $color
```